# Find array index if given value

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, search, indexing

I want to retrieve the index in the array where the value is stored. I know the value of the item at that point in the array. I'm thinking it's similar to the findIndex function in c#.
For example, array[2] = {4, 7, 8}. I know the value is 7, how do I get the value of the index, 1, if I know it is at array[1]?

Comment: Write a loop from 0 to the size of the array, compare current element to the given value, stop when found.

Comment: If you know the array is sorted, you can also use binary search

Comment: @user1798299 May I append my post to show how to use bsearch?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - just do it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow of course!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For example you can define the corresponding function the following way

```
size_t FindIndex( const int a[], size_t size, int value )
{
    size_t index = 0;

    while ( index < size && a[index] != value ) ++index;

    return ( index == size ? -1 : index );
}
```

Also instead of type size_t you can use type int.

But the better way is to use standard algorithm `std::find` or `std::find_if` declared in header `<algorithm>` provided that you use `C++`

For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 4, 7, 8 };

    auto it = std::find( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), 7 );

    if ( it != std::end( a ) )
    {
        std::cout << "The index of the element with value 7 is " 
                  << std::distance( std::begin( a ), it )
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
The index of the element with value 7 is 1
```

Otherwise you have to write the function yourself as I showed abve.:)

If the array is sorted you can use standard C function `bsearch` declared in header `<stdlib.h>`

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int cmp( const void *lhs, const void *rhs )
{
    if ( *( const int * )lhs < *( const int * )rhs ) return -1;
    else if ( *( const int * )rhs < *( const int * )lhs ) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 4, 7, 8 };

    int x = 7;
    int *p  = ( int * )bsearch( &x, a, 3, sizeof( int ), cmp );

    if ( p != NULL ) printf( "%d\n", p - a );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your first example, you have return type of `size_t`.  This is `typedef unsigned int        size_t;`, so returning a -1 may be problematic.  Your second example looks like C++.  (tagged C)

Comment: @ryyker  There is no any problem. Such a way std::string::npos is defined in C++.:)

Comment: OP is tagged C, not C++ though.  Other than that I like both approaches, except size_t cannot be negative.

Comment: @ryyker IIRC `-1` is implicitly converted to `size_t`, which is the same as `SIZE_MAX` (since overflow/underflow for unsigned integers is not UB)

Comment: @ryyker You are right that size_t can not be negative. As for all other you are wrong. -1 assigned to an object of size_t will give the maximum value of size_t. It is not important whether you deal with C or C++.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow given that the question is tagged as C, then while a C++ answer is demonstrative, it cannot be used as C code.

Comment: @Drew McGowen The more you know the better.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow true, but it's irrelevant to this particular question.

Comment: Thanks both Vlad and Drew, regarding comment on range of size_t.  I am not sure what other assertions I made that are incorrect.  The one about the OP being C is correct (unless an edit has been made my OP)

Comment: @Drew McGowen I am sure you are mistaken.

Comment: _It is not important whether you deal with C or C++_.  disagree.  There are many places (eg. some embedded systems) that do not allow C++ where C methodology is required.  Honoring the tag of the OP is usually a good idea for that reason alone.

Comment: @ryyker We are not discussing "many places". We are saying that this code is valid in C and as in C++. The problem that you simply do not know this.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - really not a big issue for me.  I am not arguing the veracity of syntax in your answer(s), all good.  And I even learned something about `size_t`.   ***Just saying*** OP is for C, not C++.  And `std::end( a )` (et. al.) is (are) not valid in C. :)

Answer (score 2):

First its important that the argument list contain size information for the array, i.e. passing a *pointer to an array* ***only*** does not provide enough information to know how many elements the array has.  The argument decays into a pointer type with no size information to the function.

So given that, you could do something like this:

```
int findIndex(int *array, size_t size, int target) 
{
    int i=0;
    while((i<size) && (array[i] != target)) i++;

    return (i<size) ? (i) : (-1);
}
```

For small arrays this approach will be fine.  For very large arrays, some sorting and a binary search would improve performance

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version **without a additional variable**.

```c
// Return index of element starting
// Return -1 if element is not present
int indexOf(const int elm, const int *ar, int ar_cnt)
{
    // decreasing array count till it reaches negative
    // arr_cnt - 1 to 0
    while (ar_cnt--)
    {
        // Return array index if current element equals provided element
        if (ar[ar_cnt] == elm)
            return ar_cnt;
    }

    // Element not present
    return -1; // Should never reaches this point
}
```

Hope the comments are self explanatory!